# Scrollbar in UserControl in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have create a UserControl added in TabPage.

```
Tabpage.AutoScroll = true;
```

After launching an application ,there is only Vertical scrollbar. When I resize the application horizontally ther is no scroll bar.

> Tabcontrol-> TabPage -> UserControl

[image]

[image]

```
        // tabPage
        // 
        this.tab_resume_new.Controls.Add(this.userControlResume);
        this.tab_resume_new.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 29);
        this.tab_resume_new.Name = "tabPage";
        this.tab_resume_new.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1270, 635);
```

In UserControl

```
 // UserControl
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoScroll = true;
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel8);
            this.Name = "UserControlResume";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1260, 625)
```

Comment: I think you should set AutoScroll on UserControl

Comment: @KarolMarianSłuszniak I tried that also.

Comment: Are you overiding the paint event in your code?

Comment: @Archlight : there is no PaintEvent in the code

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the control or is this code from the designer?

Comment: @Archlight : Code from Designer.

Comment: Can you add this UserControl to other (new) form and try what happened?

Comment: To be honest, this should work. Try to simplify. Create an empty usercontrol with only one button. and see that it works. There must be some panels or docking that is keeping the scrollbar away. When youve found out the problem please write the answer, so the next man will learn from it. Sorry I haven't been of more help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are usually just a few things that can go wrong in this situation.

1) you need to put AutoScroll on your UserControl

2) The control on your tablPage has the Anchor set to Right.. If you have Right then the horizontal scrollbar will not be shown.

3) You have nested control and the wrapper control that is in the tabPage. That wrapper control is not exceeding the tab page bounds.

Comment: there is autoscroll for UserControl and achor is not set for tabPage.
For the size , I have added the code.

Answer (score 2):

By setting `MinimumSize` for the form, it automatically insert scroll when you reduce the size less than MinimumSize